# Copy input field from one to another in a different page

Tags: java, html, wordpress, forms, input

I am trying to copy one input field to another in a different page. The scenario is when the the user press the button to submit the input field from one form goes to another form.

I would like to accomplish something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bxHQ5/

This what I have done. It copies the input field to another.

```
 <input type="text"id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" value="" >
 <input type="text" id="Username" name="Username" value="">

$("#EmailAddress").keyup(function(){
    $("#Username").val(this.value);
});
```

Here is another solution that I have found, but this one clones the input and adds a new one.

```
 <input type="text" onchange="document.body.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true))" />
```

UPDATE - I got it working - I am posting the solution for anyone who needs it

1st Form :

```
<form action="/register-form/" method="get"><input style="float: right;" name="search" type="submit" value="FREE TRIAL" />
```

2nd form :

```
<form id="registration_form" class="form-horizontal" 
action="PHP_CRM_URL_HERE" method="get" name="registration_form">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input id="yourEmail" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" 
style="height: 50px;" title="yourEmail" name="yourEmail" type="yourEmail"
value="[insert_php] echo $emailValue; [/insert_php]" placeholder="Email 
Address" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input id="yourPhone" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name"
style="height: 50px;" title="yourPhone" name="yourPhone" type="yourPhone"
placeholder="Mobile Number" />
</div>
</div>
<!--/form-group-->
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input id="yourPassword" class="form-control input-group-lg reg_name" 
style="height: 50px;" title="yourPassword" name="yourPassword"
type="yourPassword" placeholder="Password" />
</div>
</div>
<!--/form-group-->
<p style="text-align: center;"><button class="contact-submit"
style="background: #ca0002 none repeat scroll 0px 0px; border-radius: 2px; 
color: #ffffff; width: 12%; height: 45px;" 
type="submitContactForm">Register</button></p>
</form>
```

PHP Code to parse the input field from the 1st form

```
<?php
$emailValue = $_REQUEST['term'] ? $_REQUEST['term'] : null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will get you started in the direction you want to go.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvsgtnza/) just shows the basic mechanics of hiding the first form while saving its form data, then displaying a second form with that data.  If you want to hand that data to a server you will want to do an [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) request as well on submit of the first form.

If you want to do a full POST request to the server and then redirect to a new form, that would be a case for [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage).  So in your submit function, you can do something like:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('emailAddress',$('#EmailAddress').val());
```

then when you load the form on your next page you can pull the data back out to prepopulate it:

```
$('#EmailAddress').val(sessionStorage.getItem('emailAddress')||'');
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I am completely lost now. My programming skills aren't that good, can you please help me out .

Comment: I may need some more help understanding your goal.  Are you trying to duplicate information entered in one form to another form on the same page (similar to the jsfiddle)?  Or do you want to refresh the page when the user submits the first form, and present a new form with some fields prepopulated from the first?

Comment: I am trying to parse an input(email)  from one form to another form in a different page

Comment: I need more information.  How does the user arrive at the other page?  Is it presented after the first form submits?

Comment: Yes that would be perfect . When the user click the submit button on the first form it sends him to the another page with the second form

Comment: I edited my answer.  The fiddle technically stays on the same page through form submits, though the view changes.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time. the problem with your code is that the forms are in the same page  ;(

Comment: Hmm. If I saw the code you're working with I might be able to help more. Sounds like session storage is indeed what you'll need to use.

Comment: I don't have it done, I am still looking for options and so far what I have done is what I post it here :(